# How many different teams can finish the match?

Tags: combinatorics

> A hockey team plays a match. The team has $11$ players, $1$ goalkeeper, $4$ defenders, $4$ midfielders and $2$ forwards. There are $4$ substitutes; $1$ goalkeeper, $1$ defender, $1$ midfielder and $1$ forward. Each substitute can only replace a player of the same category, i.e. a defender can only replace a defender. Given that there can be a maximum of $3$ substitutes in a match, how many different teams could finish the match?
>   - A. $110$
>   - B. $118$
>   - C. $121$
>   - D. $125$
>   - E. $132$

My initial attempt included setting up a probability tree with four sections, one for each position, each with two branches, one for **substitute** and one for **not substitute**. I understand that I could only pick up to $3$ out of the $4$ **substitute** branches. which means that there are $4\choose 3$, $4\choose 2$, $4\choose 1$ or $4\choose 0$ possibilities for each of the branches along the first section, but is this correct? Because this means there are only $30$ possibilities, whereas this isn’t even near any of the answers. Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If there were no limit on substitutions, there would be two goaltenders who could be in at the end, five defenders, etc. so there would be $2 \cdot 5\cdot 5 \cdot 3=150$ finishing teams.  From this we subtract the teams that have a substitution at every position, which is $1 \cdot 4 \cdot 4 \cdot 2=32$ leaving $118$

Comment: I understand the initial part of the response, but can you maybe explain to me in words how you arrived at $1\cdot4\cdot4\cdot2=32$ for the second part? I’m trying to understand the logic behind the question so that i can do similar questions in future. Thanks

Comment: If there has been a sub at each position, we know all the reserves are on the field at the end.  The number of ways to do this is the number of ways to choose the players to take off.  You have one choice of goalie, four defenders, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

There would be ${2\choose1}{5\choose4}{5\choose4}{3\choose2}$ different teams if you could make 4 subs, so now we have to subtract the cases when all four subs are made. There are ${1\choose0}{4\choose3}{4\choose3}{2\choose1}$ cases (choose which starters to close the game)

So it is ${2\choose1}{5\choose4}{5\choose4}{3\choose2}-{1\choose0}{4\choose3}{4\choose3}{2\choose1}=150-32=118$